# The number of solutions of equations $x^2=\sigma$ in symmetric groups

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group on $n$ letters, ant let $N(\sigma,n)$ be the number of solutions of the equation $x^2=\sigma$, $\sigma\in S_n$ in $S_n$.

Is it true that

*For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and for any $\sigma\in S_n$ we have $N(e,n)\ge N(\sigma,n)$.*

(where $e\in S_n$ is the trivial permutation).

Comment: I think this is the same question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41784/roots-of-permutations/

Comment: @JoshB. Thank you, this is what I needed!